# Draw a triangle from scratch given three points

Tags: java, geometry, draw, shapes

I'm learning how to draw basic shapes using points in my graphics course, and I can't figure out **how to draw a triangle**. I thought it would be similar to drawing a rectangle, but a lot of variables (such as slope and different kinds of triangles) need to be taken into account.

Below is my working function of drawing a rectangle

```
drawRectangle(point 1, point 2){
    xStart = min(point 1.x, point 2.x)
    yStar = min(point 1.y, point 2.y)

    xEnd = max(point 1.x, point 2.x)
    yEnd = max(point 1.y, point 2.y)

    for(int i = yStart, i<= yEnd, i++){
        for(int j = xStart, j<= yEnd, j++){
            drawPoint(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

**drawRectangle** is pretty straight forward, since I just have to loop over the starting point to the ending points of the vertices. However, a triangle has three points, what should I do? I thought about maybe dividing a triangle into two halves, so each half would have a flat "base", but I am not sure if that's a viable approach or not.

Edit: Maybe I was unclear, when I say draw a triangle, I meant a color-filled triangle

Comment: Are the 3 vertices available for the triangle?

Comment: the 3 vertices are just random three points in a plane!

Comment: So is it OK to compute slopes of the 3 sides of the triangle?

Comment: Definitely. I do have a function drawLine that allows me to draw lines by given two points in the plane, not sure if that will help or not

Comment: So why not just making equations and running through the equation to get each point in between two vertices?

Comment: can you explain a bit further please? somehow I can't visualize that in my mind

Comment: Hold on. I will try to explain

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Graphics` interface for this. You just need to connect your three points with lines, like this:

```
void drawTriangle(Point one, Point two, Point three, Graphics g){
    g.drawLine(one.x, one.y, two.x, two.y);
    g.drawLine(one.x, one.y, three.x, three.y);
    g.drawLine(two.x, two.y, three.x, three.y);
}
```

This will draw a triangle, given three points and an instance of the `Graphics` object. This is a lot easier than using `for` loops.

**EDIT:**

Here is how to do this "from scratch", pixel by pixel using only the methods in your class (I am assuming that `drawPoint` draws 1 pixel), using the same "connect the dots" idea but with `for` loops:

```
drawTriangle(point 1, point 2, point 3) {
    for(int x = 1.x, x <= 2.x, x++){
        for(int y = 1.y, y <= 2.y, y++){
            drawPoint(x, y);
        }
    }
    for(int x = 1.x, x <= 3.x, x++){
        for(int y = 1.y, y <= 3.y, y++){
            drawPoint(x, y);
        }
    }
    for(int x = 2.x, x <= 3.x, x++){
        for(int y = 2.y, y <= 3.y, y++){
            drawPoint(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

This connects all 3 points to each other.

Comment: I doubt this to be what he wants :-)

Comment: This may work, but I am looking more of a from-scratch approach!

Comment: By "from scratch", do you mean without using any premade Java interfaces?

Comment: yep! similar how I implemented the drawRectangle function by going through loops and drawing it point by point

Comment: Ok, I added how to do this from scratch with `for` loops.

Comment: wouldn't that simply make three rectangles??